# Eclipse DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss5.x

In Eclipse , after i run my project on jboss 5.1 server, my deployment fails.

In my console i would get this error 
`DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR 

Deployment "vfsfile:/C:/jboss5/JBoss-5.1.0GA/server/default/deploy/ToolsPlatform-app.ear/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/jboss5/JBoss-5.1.0GA/server/default/deploy/ToolsPlatform-app.ear/ToolsPlatform-web-1.0.war/ deployment failed`

I tried:
**1.Cleaning the project. ,Doesn't work i.e Deployment of my war file fails

2.Stopping the server, cleaning ,publishing. Same error.

3.Restarting Eclipse. Works 1 out of 10 times, then after a single successful deployment, same error occurs.**

Only thing that works is , i have to

- Exit Eclipse-> go to jboss/.../server/default

  ,Then manually  deleting 3 folders 
  tmp,log,work .. 
  And
- then deleting the war file(in my case one.war) from the deploy folder.

Edit: Also if i keep on try to run my project on server, i will get this following error in my console too:

`BUILD FAILED
C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.jboss_1.6.1.v200904151730\buildfiles\jboss323.xml:12: Unable to remove existing file C:\jboss5\JBoss-5.1.0GA\server\default\deploy\one.war`

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you donot have permission to the specific folder, or you can try running eclipse as Administrator, besides you are having this permission on your device.